# Is it possible to undo deleted files on sftp/ssh?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Is it possible to undo deleted files on sftp/ssh? Please say it is so!

Comment: Depends on the server. Probably not.

Comment: @vcsjones More specifically, it depends on the file system in use (NTFS, XFS, JFS< ext[234], etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting files over SFTP/SSH is no different from running `rm` on a *NIX machine or `SHIFT+DELETE` on Windows. There is no such thing as a recycling bin for SFTP/SSH (as far as I'm aware). If you *deleted* deleted a file, then it's gone for all intents and purposes - recovering the file would most likely require special file-recovery software.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no trash bin for command line removing. But in some cases you could try to run recovery software e.g. PhotoRec from cgsecurity.org but this only works for "known" file types... (PhotoRec recognizes these files: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec)